# Adding hover text to a button when the input tag cannot be accessed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a legacy system, so please excuse the absurdity of this issue. There is a button within an input tag in a tr of a table. Users want that button to display some text Ex "This is the hover text" when they hover over the button. The html for the table is NOT editable, therefore I could not just add a title attribute containing the hover text .But I do have the ability to add input tags before the table html and I have actually added some checkboxes that control whether the rows in the table are hidden or displayed. I did this using a javascript function called by the onclick event of the input of type checkbox. Now how do I reference the input of the button and add the hover text?
Here is the code that is not editable. The Date button is the one that needs to show the hover text

```
    <th>
    <input name="iDate" id="iDate" type="button" value="Date">
    </th>
```

Comment: Could you possibly share a snippet of the html, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by manipulating the `input[type="button"]` with mouseenter and mouseleave

You didn't show any code, so I will throw this rock in this empty room and hope it helps

```js
$("input[type='button']")
  .mouseover(function() {
    $(this).text("My hover text");
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(this).text("");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="button" />
```

If you run this in the browser dev tools you will see the text loading on mouseenter. Now you just have to modify this to pass styleable code